# Most efficient way to iterate through large dataframe converting strings of numbers to ints

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains two columns which are both of type str. These columns generally contain numbers in them, but there also exists the occasional word/non-num character.

Example df

```
A    B    Name
25   X    R
600  243  B
Z@   650  Y
633  18   G
```

I am trying to filter the dataframe so that I only keep rows in which the element in A **OR** B is between 600-699. I cant cast the columns as type int because of the occasional non number.

I have tried the following code to iterate row by row and change number strings to ints, and then filter.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        df = df['A'].astype(int)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        df = df['B'].astype(int)
    except:
        pass

df = df[ (df['A'] | df['B']) > 599]
df = df[ (df['A'] | df['B']) < 700]
```

Result df

```
A    B    Name
600  243  B
Z@   650  Y
633  18   G
```

Iterating through each row is very slow especially when dealing with 100k+ rows in a dataframe. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this more efficiently?

Comment: This question has some good information with regards to performance when working with Pandas dataframe [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues)

Answer (score 2):

Even though you don't want to convert non-numeric values to numeric, it is going to be most efficient to operate on numerical Series as a whole, rather than row by row.

Here is a way for you to convert each desired column to a numeric Series using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), and then `or` each mask using `np.logical_or.reduce` across every mask at once.  This  will allow you to scale this solution to any number of columns efficiently.

---

```
def fn(s, mn, mx):
    return pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').between(mn, mx)

m = np.logical_or.reduce([fn(df[col], 600, 699) for col in ('A', 'B')])

df.loc[m]
```

```
     A    B Name
1  600  243    B
2   Z@  650    Y
3  633   18    G
```